# Can't catch HttpRequestException when using HttpMessageHandler

Tags: .net-5, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using HttpMessageHandler to log Http Request and Response. If internet connection is not available I get HttpRequestException, but this Exception is not catched (try catch not working). If I don't use HttpMessageHandler Exception is catched.

Method with try catch :

```
public JObject Get()
    {
        string url = "/...";
        try
        {
            using (var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler())
            {
                httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert,
                chain, errors) =>
                { return true; };

                using (var client = new HttpClient(new LoggingHandler(httpClientHandler)))
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                             new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(CONTENT_TYPE_JSON));

                    var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new
                    System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                    Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

                    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;

                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    JObject rss = JObject.Parse(json);

                    return rss;                        

                }
            }
        }
        catch(HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            //Catch not working
            return null;
        }
    }
```

HttpMessageHandler :

```
public class LoggingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(LoggingHandler));
    public LoggingHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler)
        : base(innerHandler)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, 
               CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;

        Loging("Request:");
        Loging(request.ToString());

        if (request.Content != null)
        {
            Loging(await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        }
        Loging("");

        response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        Loging("Response:");
        Loging(response.ToString());
        if (response.Content != null)
        {
            Loging(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        }
        Loging("");

        return response;
    }

    private void Loging(string message)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(message);
        log.Info(message);
    }

}
```

Why is it happining?